# Evento não é amarrado ao elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos

Tenho um evento no **jQuery** (versão 1.5) da seguinte forma:

```js
 $('#refresh_abertos').click(function(){
      // aqui o código irrelevante nesta pergunta     
 });
```

Acontece que o meu elemento `#refresh_abertos` só é carregado posteriormente via **ajax**, e o `.click()` não fica amarrado a ele, como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Problema

Pela altura em que o teu código está a ser lido, o teu elemento não existe na página, pelo que a anexação do evento de `click` não chega a ocorrer.

## Solução

Em alternativa ao já sugerido, se pretendes anexar um evento de `click` a um elemento que ainda não existe *ainda*, podes anexar o mesmo a um elemento que seja `parent`, como é o caso do `body` ou uma *wrapper* que está presente na página no carregamento inicial da mesma.

## Exemplo Prático

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/DY4ML/)

<sup>No exemplo utilizei o setTimeout para simular a inserção de um elemento no DOM um bocado após a leitura da página.</sup>

Não sei a tua *markup*, pelo que fica um exemplo assumindo que o teu elemento `#refresh_abertos` vai ser colocado dentro de uma `div` que contém o ID `#myWrapper`:

```js
$('#myWrapper').on("click", "#refresh_abertos", function() {
    alert("bubu");
});
```

O que estamos a fazer aqui é anexar o evento de `click` na `div#myWrapper` a ser despoletado quando o mesmo tem efeito no elemento `#refresh_abertos`.

Assim ficas com o `click` num elemento pai que vai ter efeito quando clicas no elemento que virá a ser introduzido.

---

A solução apresentada faz uso do jQuery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) disponível a partir da versão 1.7.

Comment: Houveram outras respostas como essa, mais o @Zuul foi o primeiro a indicar usando uma div pai do elemento, o que no caso é o mais ideal, por isso estou aceitando sua resposta como correta.

Answer (score 8):

A melhor solução que eu vejo é delegar o click via document (ou um parente que esteja presente desde que a página carregou).

Assim você pode usar:

```
 $(document).on('click','#refresh_abertos',function(){
      // aqui o código irrelevante nesta pergunta     
 });
```

Usando o [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) você pode fazer com que o "handler" seja aplicado ao `document` (uma carta segura, como disse podia ser um outro parente), mas delegado a `#refresh_abertos`

Para versões anteriores ao jQuery 1.7 pode usar-se [**.delegate()**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) em vêz de `.on()`

Comment: Também é possível usar [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) além de `.delegate` (embora não saiba se há diferença significativa de performance)

Comment: @mgibsonbr dei uma olhada __[aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579117/jquery-live-vs-delegate)__ e achei melhor sugerir o `.delegate()`

Answer (score 7):

Supondo que você esteja usando uma função como a [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Adicione o código no *callback* do evento, isto é, uma função que o jQuery executa ao *concluir* tanto a requisição quanto a atualização do DOM.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
$("#local_carregamento").load("ajax/pagina.html", function() {

   $('#refresh_abertos').click(function(){
      // aqui o código irrelevante nesta pergunta   
   });

});
```

E mais um exemplo usando a função [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```js
$.ajax("example.php")
  .done(function() {
     $('#refresh_abertos').click(function(){
        // aqui o código irrelevante nesta pergunta   
     });
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

*Note que, segundo a documentação, os callbacks `success`, `error` e `complete` estão depreciados a partir da versão 1.8.*

Comment: Na verdade eu utilizo o `$.ajax` mesmo, vou colocar no `success`.

Comment: @KennyRafael Certo, adicionei mais um exemplo para deixar a reposta completa. Além disso, se você usa jQuery 1.8 ou superior, considere o uso do callback `done`, conforme o exemplo.

Comment: Neste projeto utilizo a versão 1.5, nunca utilizei esta sintaxe que você colocou, ela serve pra esta versão também?

Comment: @KennyRafael Existe alguma razão específica para se usar uma versão tão antiga? Se for possível atualizar, atualize, isso inclusive tornará seu sistema mais compatível com a maioria dos *browsers* (atuais e antigos).

Comment: @KennyRafael Meu exemplo não vai servidor para você. No seu caso tem que ser o 3º parâmetro como nos exemplos de outras respostas. E, como mencionado, procure atualizar a versão... ;)

Comment: Infelizmente não posso atualizar a versão...

Answer (score 6):

Você pode usar o método [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (em versões mais recentes do jQuery, [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)):

```javascript
$("#refresh_abertos").live("click", function() { ... });
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/V83PC/1/). Citando a documentação do `live` (ênfase minha):

> Coloca um manipulador de eventos para todos os elementos que casam com o seletor utilizado, **agora e no futuro**.

Nota: o método `live` está obsoleto a partir da versão `1.7`, sendo o `on` a maneira preferencial:

```javascript
$("body").on("click", "#refresh_abertos", function() { ... });
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/V83PC/). A vantagem do `on` é que ele coloca o handler não no próprio elemento, mas em algum elemento ancestral (nesse exemplo escolhi o `body`, mas poderia ser outro mais restrito), e ele reage a eventos em qualquer elemento descendente que passe no filtro escolhido (o segundo argumento, um seletor). Desse modo, elementos adicionados depois também são contemplados, e sem um custo excessivo de performance (o `live`, se não me engano, precisa checar novamente o seletor sempre que um elemento é adicionado ao DOM, em qualquer parte da página).

Answer (score 5):

A solução mais simples e óbvia que consigo imaginar agora, rapidamente, é fazer o "bind" **após** o carregamento do elemento via AJAX. Olhe na [API](http://api.jquery.com/) do método que você está usando para fazer a requisição, faça o bind no success que deve funcionar.