# jQuery não reconhece evento .click de uma classe adicionada com append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gente, não estou conseguindo fazer com que o evento .click de um botão que é adicionado com o comando append funcione.

Eis a função que contém o append:

```
    function mostrarUploads(nome, tabela) {

    var $table = $(tabela);
    $table.html("");

    //apenas atualiza as categorias caso esteja abrindo o collapse, nunca quando está fechando
    showPleaseWait();

    $.ajax({
      url: "/painel/mostrarUploadsCategorias",
      method: 'POST',
      data: {_token: jQuery(".token").val(), nome: nome},

      success: function(e) {

        e.forEach(function(item, indice) {
            //remove o diretório da string e só deixa o nome final do arquivo
            var nomeArquivo = item.replace('public/painel/categorias/' + nome + "/", ""); 
            $table.append("<tr><td>" + nomeArquivo + "</td> <td><a class='btn btn-success' href=\"/painel/fazerDownload/" + nome + "/" + nomeArquivo + "\">Download</a> <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger excluirUpload' data-diretorio=\"" + item + "\">Excluir</button></td></tr>");
        });
      }
    }).done(function() {        //só abre o modal assim que terminar a requisição ajax
        hidePleaseWait();
    });

}
```

E o evento click do botão:

```
    jQuery(function() {

... algumas outras funções...

        $(".excluirUpload").click(
            function() {
                alert('excluindo');
                //carregar os uploads desta categoria
                var diretorio = $(this).data('diretorio');
                var $table = $(this).closest('.categoria').find("tbody");

                excluirUpload(diretorio, $table);
            }
        );
    });
```

Seria por causa do .append, esse evento de .click não está reconhecendo a classe desse botão?? Como proceder??

Outra coisa que eu tentei foi chamar uma função com o onclick, mas preciso passar  essa $table como parâmetro e, ao chegar na função como parâmetro, se eu imprimir, meu retorno é [Object object]. Qualquer uma das duas aproximações seriam úteis, mas não consegui fazer nenhuma das duas funcionar.

Obrigado!

Comment: use `$(document).on('click', '.excluirUpload', function(){})`

Comment: Isso ajudou, cara, obrigado. Se quiser escrever como resposta, fique a vontade. Ainda assim não consegui entender o porque a minha aproximação não funciona...

Comment: Como esses elementos foram adicionados à página após o carregamento da mesma através do método `append`, eles não reconhecerão o evento `click` chamando do modo tradicional `$(".excluirUpload").click`, diante disso, é necessário delegar o evento `click` via `document`, como o colega mencionou acima, pois ai ele irá buscar em todo o documento HTML (toda a página), inclusive em elementos adicionados posteriormente ao carregamento da mesma, os elementos que possuam a  `class` especificada  (.excluirUpload) para aplicar a função especificada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa inscrever o evento desta maneira

```
$(document).click('.excluirUpload', function(){ ... });
```

Isso acontece porque o seu código é executado sempre que a página é completamente carregada (`ready`) e depois de ter os elementos carregados o JavaScript adiciona estes listeners a eles.

Porém, você está adicionando um novo elemento e não está adicionando um *listener* a este elemento em específico.

Da forma que eu mostrei acima, o evento é atrelado **ao documento HTML** e o segundo parâmetro faz com que ele só seja disparado se for disparado por algum elemento com o seletor especificado.

Veja algumas publicações sobre estes assuntos que podem te ajudar:

- [Evento não é amarrado ao elemento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2276/evento-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-amarrado-ao-elemento)
- [Qual a diferença entre $(document).ready() e window.onload?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182797/18246)