# Botão não funciona ao ultilizar o append / prepend

Tags: html, jquery

Estou tentando colocar um `button` pelo `append` pegado via ajax. Depois de ser colocado em `html`, o `button` para de funcionar, (funciona tudo normalmente depois de atualizar a página, pois 'pega' os dados do banco), já pesquisei em diversos lugares, porém não encontrei, Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor?

---

```
$('.clearfix button').on("click", function() {

     // e é pegado pelo ajax 'success' em formato json

     $('.shopping-cart-items').append(resultado['dado']);
});
```

[image: Este é o retorno do json]

(desculpa pelo formato do meu post, pois não sei usar esse site direito ainda)

Comment: Você pode postar seu código para analisarmos mais a fundo seu problema ?

Comment: Recomendo a leitura de [Evento não é amarrado ao elemento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2276/3635) e [Qual a diferença entre $(document).ready() e window.onload?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182797/3635) para entender como de fato funciona o processo de carregamento básico do DOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu problema é de *delegação*, onde elementos adicionados de forma dinâmica na página não estão no DOM. Para resolver isso, altere o seu *onclick* para:

```
$(document).on("click", '.clearfix button', function(){
```

Assim o `click` será capturado também em novos elementos com o seletor especificado.

Comment: Nossa, valeu mesmo cara, estava 'quebrando a cabeça' pra fazer isso, sério muito obrigado!! (a todos)